# how to pass a value in blueimp file uploader?

Tags: php, javascript, json, jquery, blueimp

http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/

**Sequence:**

In this file uploader that i used, I want to pass a value using the **$_GET['id']** request like this:

> http://mysite.com/message?id=2

**Problem:**

**$_GET['id']=2** could not be read inside the **upload_class.php** or **index.php** inside the folder of /server/php/. What is the best way to read the value of **$_GET['id']** from the program?

can someone who is familiar with the program that can help me? thanks in advance
...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send data through the form which posts when you upload an image.

There are two ways to do this.  Get or Post the data.

---

## GET

**Alter the `action` attribute of the form to include the additional parameter:**

```
<form action="blueimp/php/index.php?id=2" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Access the variable in index.php with:**

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

---

## POST

**Add an input field to the form with the value that you would like to pass through:**

```
<form action="blueimp/php/index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">


  <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2" />


  <div style="float:left;">
    <label class="fileinput-button">
      <span>Add Images</span>
      <input id="fileSelector" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </label>
    <button type="button" class="delete">Delete Selected</button>
    <button type="button" class="checkAll">Check All</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**Access the variable in index.php with:**

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: wow hope it will work...need to work for this for a moment...tnx

Comment: I have this implemented in multiple locations on my site.  Should work like a treat :)

Comment: now for the deletion of the data in my database..can you share me where i should put my code to delete the filename of the file to be deleted? tnx again... :)

Comment: Ask a separate question and I'll take a look at it.  It's good to keep  questions separate so that they can benefit others further down the road.